# topbar attach to left side bar

Tags: html, css

I want to attach my top bar to my left-sidebar, I have no idea how to do, I didn't use any bootstrap or any frameworks, I'm doing all from scratch.

```
<header id="header">

</header>
<div id="left_col" class="column fixed open">

</div>

#left_col {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:240px;
    z-index:3;
}

#header {
    width: 85.5%;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    background-color:black;
    height:50px;
}

#left_col:before {
   content:"";
   display:block;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   width:1px;
   z-index:4;
   background: #000;
}
```

[image]

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/z4axLrbo/

I want to attached the top black bar toward the vertical line no matter how window's width decrease, the black top bar always attached to the vertical line.

Comment: attach means?  you want header inside the sidebar or attach at the side of the sidebar ?

Comment: @Saajan attach at the sidebar.... like the black top bar against the vertical line...

Comment: something like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/vaca4n7w/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#left_col {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:240px;
    z-index:3;
    border-left:1px solid #000;
}

#left_col:before {
   content:"";
   display:block;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   width:1px;
   z-index:4;
   background: #000;
}

#header {
    top:0px;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left:240px;
    background-color:black;
    height:50px;
```

}

Use this css :)

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/Im_Saajan/w8fr9f9g/

update : Here is the code without `::before` Pseudo Element

```
#left_col {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:240px;
    z-index:3;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    height:500px;
}

#header {
    top:0px;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left:240px;
    background-color:black;
    height:50px;
}
```

Demo 2 : https://jsfiddle.net/Im_Saajan/L4po61sk/

Comment: Can you explain why use before ?

Comment: Actually ::before pseudo element is not required... you can add the same css directly to the #left_col element... i shall edit the code without ::before and post it.... and for more info about pseudo element refer this article [link] (https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/ )

Answer (score 0):

Just Change `float:right;`

to

```
float:left;
```

See Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ag45vam5/)

Comment: Didn't understood. Please explain what you want in detail.